# Can't access hadoop with ip address

Tags: linux, hadoop

I'm following [this guide](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/) for installing hadoop in centos.

Everything works normal when I run hadoop and I compare it with the guide also, but when I try to access mine with ip address like `192.168.0.1:50070` then nothing works.

Here is the output when I run had:

```
bash-4.2$ start-dfs.sh
14/10/15 16:28:30 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-localhost.localdomain.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-localhost.localdomain.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-localhost.localdomain.out
14/10/15 16:29:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Do you think I have to configure IP somewhere to access them? My configuration is exactly the same as above link, even the xml files...

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to disable the firewall/make an ip tables line for it on the master/slaves?

for centOS6.5, try:

```
service firewall stop
```

to disable the firewall. If it works properly, you just need to add the allowance to your iptables.

Also, CentOS has the SELinux. I would advice turning it off and check if it keeps with an error.

Comment: I did that and nothing same old ... do I have to add any IP in host file or anything? as it shows when I start the hdf ip as 0.0.0.0 in the log I put question

Comment: whats the IP address of your master(server)/default gateway for master/ and /etc/hosts on it?

Comment: I have installed single node it's not cluster... and FYI I can access it from within server but from IP I cannot: i'e localhost:50070 i can access but with 192.168.0.1:50070 I cannot access it from network

Comment: I guess it's because you are binding it to the localhost interface (lo) by default. When you do 'ifconfig' on console you are probably seeing at least two interfaces. The hadoop is binded to the local host interface (127.0.0.1). At least with cloudera manager I know there is a way to solve this for cluster. I assume that there must be for single node too. I have made this same question some time ago. The link is:
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!msg/scm-users/MrEQicljPBM/nbkkquW_sVkJ

Comment: Hi, how can I bind it to eth0... I even change the core-site.xml from localhost to the main IP  
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://172.30.10.105:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
 still not working from network but works fine from the machine itself.

Comment: Maybe you can try commenting your second line in /etc/hosts file
(the one with the 127.0.0.1 entry). Then restart Hadoop and HDFS.
Check then, on netstat, if the NameNome is now binding in 192.168.0.1

Let me know if that works so I can update my post ;)